# Why can't I type to the chat when I join the server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I go to a local server, it says to me that I need to login, but I can't type to the chat button. So how can I login to play server?

Here is a picture:

[image: Minecraft PE saying 'You are not logged in']

Comment: Also, is this a Bukkit/Spigot/Sponge/Vanilla/any-PC-client-server or a PocketMine/Vanilla/any-Pocket-Edition-server?

Comment: Are you sure you can't press the chat button?

Comment: The server you're playing on may [have this installed](https://github.com/PocketMine/SimpleAuth). Have you tried the same commands as [this Bukkit Plugin (xAuth)](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/xauth/)? | Basically `/register [password]` and then every time you log onto that server `/login [password]`

Comment: What is the IP address of the server you're playing on? (I'll write you some instructions)

Comment: IP:sg.lbsg.net,this Is the IP

Comment: Dang. It was closed while I was writing an answer. :/ Also, try pressing the chatbox button on the top right corner, next to the pause button and check your internet connection.

Comment: [Definitely working](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0AJ7P.png)

Answer (score -1):

I get that all the time. If you have an android, you need to restart your mcpe account. If you have iOS, you need to press the home button twice and swipe up Minecraft PE. Then go back into Minecraft and press that same server and done!

Comment: Can you explain how to restart the mcpe account?